# size of slide numbers reveal js

Tags: reveal.js

I've added slide numbers to my reveal js presentation with

```
        Reveal.configure({ slideNumber: true });
        Reveal.configure({ slideNumber: 'c/t' });
```

But the slide numbers are very small. I'm not familiar with javascript. Can someone please tell me how to make them bigger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

adding

```
.reveal .slide-number {
  font-size: 24pt;
  color: #ffffff; }
```

To the css did the trick